# Succesfuly installing Ubuntu 18 after Win10 but cannot see boot option

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04

I succesfully installed Ubuntu 18.04 on top of pre-installed Windows 10 in a HP Probook 440 G3. It boots straight into Windows. The only way to load Ubuntu is pressing the f9 key, and choosing Ubuntu manually. How can i make permanently booting to Ubuntu as the first choice?

Comment: update: The second problem is gone by simply running software updater.

Comment: See HP site for changing boot order: https://support.hp.com/vn-en/document/c00364979